# Change in format for awk

Tags: bash, awk

My line of code is below.

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "gnome-terminal"}
           {printf " --tab -e  \"telnet "$4" "$6 " |  tee " $1$12"\" -t \"" $1" "$12 "\""  }
     END   {printf "\n"}' temp1.prm >> abc
```

Output gives this in abc:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e  "telnet 10.31.248.104 3007 |  tee dutA1MM1" -t "dutA1 MM1"
```

I have to get below format:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "telnet 10.31.248.104 3007 | tee script1.log"' -t "dutA1 MM1"
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What's the larger goal here? If you're going to execute the `gnome-terminal` commands afterwards there's likely a better way to do what you want than generating commands with awk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this double-quotes quoted format:

```
awk "BEGIN {printf \"gnome-terminal\"} {printf \" --tab -e  'bash -c \\\"telnet \"\$4\" \"\$6 \" |  tee \" \$1\$12\"\\\"' -t \\\"\" \$1\" \"\$12 \"\\\"\"  } END { printf \"\\n\"}" temp1.prm >> abc
```

Testing with `echo`, the argument to `awk` would literally be

```
BEGIN {printf "gnome-terminal"} {printf " --tab -e  'bash -c \"telnet "$4" "$6 " |  tee " $1$12"\"' -t \"" $1" "$12 "\""  } END { printf "\n"}
```

Comment: @user2796211 I actually made mistakes before. Please try again. And also, don't use the second one. It's only an interpretation.

Comment: Well that's odd. A dummy command like this: `awk "BEGIN {printf \"gnome-terminal\"} {printf \" --tab -e  'bash -c \\\"telnet \"\$4\" \"\$6 \" |  tee \" \$1\$12\"\\\"' -t \\\"\" \$1\" \"\$12 \"\\\"\"  } END { printf \"\\n\"}"  < <(echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM)` gives me an output of `gnome-terminal --tab -e  'bash -c "telnet 5223 27466 |  tee 6455"' -t "6455 "`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get into a quoting nightmare. You could keep things tidy like so:

```
BEGIN {
    double_quote = "\""
    s1 = "gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "
    s2 = double_quote "telnet 10.31.248.104 3007 | tee script1.log" double_quote
    s3 = "' -t dutA1 MM1"

    printf "%s%s%s\n",s1,s2,s3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
awk '{ printf "gnome-terminal --tab -e \047bash -c \"telnet %s %s | tee script1.log\"\047 -t \"%s %s\"\n", $4, $6, $1, $12 }' file
```

but since you didn't provide sample input and expected output it's just a guess.